# display same table data in multiple times on click of add button using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having 3 text boxes in a table if i click add button the same text boxes need to append in the same page using javascript.Please help me

Comment: Please provide us with example code or a jsFiddle (jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 1):

Ypur question is not clear but i guess you want something like this

```
function buttonClick(parent){
var test = document.createElement("input");
test.setAttribute("type", "text");
test.setAttribute("name", "someName");

parent.appendChild(test);
}
```

call this function on button click event with a parent element as arguement

Comment: Hi anu my question is i am having 3 text boxes in a page .if i click add button the same 3 text boxes need to append in the same page.using javascript.

Comment: place your textboxes inside a div or some other container, then call this function on add button click event. Put a loop to create 3 boxes.Dont feel shy to ask if u still cant make it to work